# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Trying to send data to controller using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, post

I'm trying to send data to controller using ajax and I'm getting **The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.**
Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

In web.php

```
Route::post('/fb', 'FormController@fb')->name('fb');
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="formfb" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-route="{{ route('fb') }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button id="fbbutton" type="submit" class="dropdown-item">Save</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script language="javascript">

  $('#formfb').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var w= <?php echo $resolution['width'] ;?>;
    var h= <?php echo $resolution['height'] ;?>;
     $("#picture").show();
html2canvas($('#picture'), {
width: w,
height: h
}).then(function(canvas) {
  var inputURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');   
  var binaryVal; 
  var inputMIME = inputURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]; 
  if (inputURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0) 
      binaryVal = atob(inputURI.split(',')[1]); 
  else
      binaryVal = unescape(inputURI.split(',')[1]); 
  var blobArray = []; 
  for (var index = 0; index < binaryVal.length; index++) { 
      blobArray.push(binaryVal.charCodeAt(index)); 
  } 
  var blobObject = new Blob([blobArray], { 
            type: inputMIME 
        }); 
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("blob", blobObject, "blob");



        var route= $('#form-data').data();
        var form_data= $(this);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: route,
          headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
         data: form_data.serialize(),
          success: function(Response){
            console.log(Response);
          }

}); 
})
</script>
```

Routes list:

[image: route:list]

!!!UPDATE!!!

[image: post2]

[image: post3]

Comment: Check the network tab in browser dev tools to see what request is being made via ajax.

Comment: Did you mean this?

Request URL: http://localhost/MatchmakingForms/public/?_token=1neYEMeaiRhXLFq1JzjBRLI8OaMoGjoOcLYySWHu
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: If you do `console.log(route)` just before the ajax request, what does it log

Comment: It doesn't log anything.

Comment: @hcphoon is onto something, I think you're not making the request on `/fb` and that's why the request method is not supported. In other words, the `route` variable seems to be the problem. But to make sure, you should check if it returns the expected value.

Comment: @GabrijelBatista What about `console.log($('#formfb').data('route'))`? If I get it correctly, the form ID is wrong and the data key is missing.

Comment: I tried what he suggested and it's still not working and there is nothing in console except 405 (Method Not Allowed).

Comment: Did you try executing `console.log($('#formfb').data('route'))`? That should output `/fb`. Please, let me know about that and @ me so I get a notification for your comments.

Comment: @Zeke yes I did and it doesnt output anything. and I dont get /fb in url, only token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note**: this answer is the result of a long chat session where many things were tested out.

The following code is now working after some changes on Apache's and PHP's configurations:

## JavaScript / jQuery

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function fb() {
        let id = "{{ $user['id'] }}";
        let email = "{{ $user['email'] }}";
        $("#picture").show();
        html2canvas($('#picture'), {
            width: {{ $resolution['width'] }},
            height: {{ $resolution['height'] }}
        }).then(function (canvas) {
            let imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{ route('fb') }}',
                dataType: 'text',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                data: {
                    base64data: imgData,
                    userid: id,
                    useremail: email
                }
            });
            let imgsrc = document.getElementById("imgfb").src;
            window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + encodeURIComponent(imgsrc), "pop", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=no");
        })
    }
</script>
```

## PHP

```
Route::post('/fb', 'FormController@fb')->name('fb');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your `url` parameter in the AJAX request dynamic, you can simply do

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: {!!route('fb')!!},
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: form_data.serialize(),
    success: function (Response) {
        console.log(Response);
    }
});
```

doing `{!! <PHP Code> !!}` allows you to pass PHP into your JS

Comment: @GabrijelBatista whats the issue now?

Comment: Same issue. And console still shows only POST 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Try hard coding the url, i.e. `url: '/fb'`

Comment: Tried it already. I also tried to make separate script and function only for this ajax request to see if there might be something else in the script that was causing this problem but still the same issue.

Comment: Yes I did and still same.
I have noticed that when error shows up I get in my url: .../public/?_token=1neYEMeaiRhXLFq1JzjBRLI8OaMoGjoOcLYySWHu but when I add "fb" between "/" and "?" the error says that GET method is not supported. Supported method: POST